# Applinks in android not opening installed app

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

We've implemented applinks in our android app, but they seem to be misbehaving when links are being opened in apps other than Facebook.

Even though our app is installed in our phone, when we press a link which was shared to any other app (whatsapp, gmail, etc.) it will open the play store.
However, pressing the same link from within Facebook will invoke the desired flow:  Open the app if it is installed or prompt to download the app from the play store if not.

How can we get the links in other apps to open our app if it is already installed?

The following tags exist in our `<HEAD>`:

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="ourappname://">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.ourappname.app">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="ourappname">
<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
```

And the following definitions in our Manifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="ourappname" />
</intent-filter>
```

What are we missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, you would need to convince those apps to support app links.

Comment: I disagree.  More than once I pressed a link that was shared to me on one of those apps, and the link opened the app on my phone. Try it yourself. Share a tweet to someone in Whatsapp and then press the link. If you have the twitter app it will the link will open inside the app. Same with pinterest...

Comment: There are many ways to cause an app to open in Android. Native apps can also register to handle http:// urls inside their app. This is likely how those links are opening in the app. Intent filters, however, doesn't give you some advantages that app links can give you.

Comment: your url is not appropriate ,
please see this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253760/unable-to-get-applinks-with-rivets-component-working-on-android
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ur using deeplink instead of applink . u can do as this page to[Enabling Deep Links for App Content](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)
and u can add android applink like this [applinks](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html)